# What does the p-value in ggscatter refers to ? [R language]

Tags: r, correlation, hypothesis-test

I graphed my data of x and y using ggscatter in R. I have a result of R = 0.4 and p < 2.2e-16. I know R means that the correlation value between x and y is 0.4. However, what does the p value refer to ? I know that in hypothesis testing, we can reject the null hypothesis when the p-value is close to 0. However, in this case, what is the null hypothesis for us to reject ?

Comment: that the correlation coefficient is not zero?

Comment: I see, so that means that when we plot the points, our null hypothesis is that there's no correlation between x and y (R=0).
Since p<0.001, we will reject the null hypothesis at 99.9% significant level as there is sufficient evidence to show that x and y do indeed have a correlation greater than 0

Comment: Different from 0, not greater.